# How can i make the code show a new background when i press just one time a key?

Tags: python, keyboard, pygame

Please help me i've started very recently writting programs in pygame and i can pass this obstacle i can't find any help online. So to be more specific what i need is something that when i press maybe the tab key just once beacause if i put KEYDOWN i would have to me always pressing the key i would get out of the starting background and then would appear a message. Thank you for your time.

```
    import pygame
    import random
    perguntaa = random.randint(1,2)
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
    RED = (255, 0, 0)
    BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
    ORANGE = (255, 154, 23)
    pygame.init()
    size = (700, 500)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Quem quer ser Milionário")
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
        screen.fill(ORANGE)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [225, 200, 250, 100])
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('cambria', 100, False, False)
        text = font.render("Play", True, WHITE)
        screen.blit(text, [225, 200])
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
            screen.fill(ORANGE)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [0, 50, 700, 100])
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe this is what you are looking for

```
bgs = [Orange, Black, Green]
current_bg = 0
if event.key == pygame.K_Q:
    current_bg += 1
    if current_bg > len(bgs)-1:
        current_bg = 0
screen.fill(bgs[current_bg] #alternately screen.blit(bgs[current_bg]) if bgs indexes are instead sprites
screen.update()#flip and update are interchangeable however update is more commonly used
```